Change Note Values for Second Repetition?
I'm transcribing my Scanned Score into museScore (OS: Windows 10 (10.0), Arch.: x86_64, MuseScore version (64-bit): 3.6.2.548021803, revision: github-musescore-musescore-3224f34)

As you can see in the Red Rectangles there are simultaneus or overlapped notes (different Note values).
The Red Rectangles show the note value variations in a repetition in two non-consecutive measures.
The song is repeated completely, but with variations of note values ​​in those measures.
As you can see in the Text, the first has different note value to second one.

For repeat I found this video: 


I was confused and I used multiple voices



Here a screenshot of my museScore:

Then the question is:
How change the values note for second repeat?
I was trying with Prima Volta and Seconda Volta, but they did not work!

Probably the same problem: https://musescore.org/en/node/282465 and https://musescore.org/en/node/1684 and https://musescore.org/en/node/337283

My question https://musescore.org/en/node/363535

In MuseScore, one can add multiple "voices". Here are instructions for MuseScore 4.

Enter the main notes.



Select voice 2 from the toolbar.



Enter the second set of notes, including rests where there are no notes to be played.



Select each rest and uncheck its "visible" property. (In earlier versions of MuseScore, this option is in the Inspector.)



Select the note for which a small note head is desired, and check the "small notehead" box. (In earlier versions of MuseScore, this option is in the Inspector.)



Thanks Aaron for your valueable response (Please, Don't erase it), Sorry for my mistake, I found out that the note values ​​are different for the second repetition.

The item 4, the Properties..., how I can get visible? Ahh I'm using museScore 3.6.2

The properties for #4 and #5 are in the Element Inspector.

@joseluisbz I gather something didn't work about the answer I provided. Please clarify the problem.
